# SQL database in Azure is unreliable

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I often get "The specified network name is no longer available" multiple times when trying to connect in Management Studio, and I also get this error through code. Transient fault handling doesn't seem to completely solve the issue. I haven't faced this issue before with Azure databases (at least from what I can remember).

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Could you try this solutions from here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52467ff5-cfc7-457b-88af-d3a4920091df/the-specified-network-name-is-no-longer-available?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Comment: I actually created that post some time ago. Added the retry logic but it doesn't seem to work 100% of the time. Also, I find it very weird that I have to make multiple connection attempts in Management Studio in order to successfully connect to the db